# Inverted circle radius calculation

Tags: javascript, geometry

I want to calculate the radius of an inverted circle.

I managed to implement everything but, after hours of struggle, I could not find a formula to calculate the correct inverted radius.

More info about circle inversion:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sG_6nlMZ8f4

My code so far: http://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/Mwjdga

It seems to be working but you can easily tell it's totally wrong.

```
var c = $('#c'),
    b = $('body'),
    canvas = c[0],
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    pi = Math.PI,
    r = 100,
    mr = 30,
    width, height, hw, hh;
var setup = function() {
  width = b.width();
  height = b.height();
  hw = width/2;
  hh = height/2;
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  mid();
};
var mid = function() {
  circle(hw,hh,0.25);
  circle(hw,hh,r);
}
var circle = function(x,y,r) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,pi*2);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
};
var move = function(evt) {
  var x = evt.clientX,
      y = evt.clientY;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
  mid();
  circle(x,y,mr);
  var dx = x-hw,
      dy = y-hh,
      d = dist(dx,dy),
      nd = r*r/d,
      nx = dx*nd/d,
      ny = dy*nd/d,
      nr = mr*mr*pi/d; // whats the correct formula?
  console.log(nr);
  circle(nx+hw, ny+hh, nr);
};
var dist = function(x,y) {
  return Math.pow(x*x + y*y, 1/2);
};
$(setup);
$(window).resize(setup);
$(window).mousemove(move);
```

Need help from the math experts!

Comment: Could you explain what you're actually trying to do, in words please.

Comment: "I want to calculate the radius of a reflected circle" .. sorry but I can't be more clear...

Comment: You're going to have to be more clear: that's a 26 minute video you link to. You could at least isolate the times describing what you're thinking about. Or try to find a different web link.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "reflected circle"? Explain it here or provide a link to detailed explanation (preferaby on wiki-resource). We don't want to go to that video.

Comment: Ok you lazy ... hope one of you will try to answer it now ... rsrssss

Comment: I edited your question to use the correct terminology. The reason why people were confused is because in geometry, the radius of a **reflected** circle is the same as the original - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28mathematics%29

Comment: thx @slebetman ... I just got what I'm doing wrong .. gonna post as soon as I fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was that I was assuming that the center of the inverted circle also respected OP x OP' = r<sup>2</sup>, but as the image below shows, it clearly does not. The solution was to calculate two points on the circle and reflect each one, then use half the distance between this points to find the radius.

[image]

So this is the correct code:

```js
var c = $('#c'),
  b = $('body'),
  canvas = c[0],
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  fixedRadius = 100,
  saved = [], 
  width, height,
  half = {
    w: 0,
    h: 0
  },
  mouse = {
    r: 31,
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  reflect = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    r: 0
};

var setup = function() {
  width = b.width();
  height = b.height();
  half.w = width/2;
  half.h = height/2;
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  move();
};

var mid = function() {
  circle(half.w,half.h,1.5);
  circle(half.w,half.h,fixedRadius);
};

var circle = function(x,y,r,c) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = c || 'black';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
};

var line = function(x1,y1,x2,y2,c) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = c || 'black';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
  ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
};

var axis = function () {
  line(half.w,0,half.w,height,'#ccc');
  line(0,half.h,width,half.h,'#ccc');
};

var move = function(evt) {
  mouse.x = evt ? evt.clientX : half.w;
  mouse.y = evt ? evt.clientY : half.h + 11;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
  axis();
  mid();
  circle(mouse.x,mouse.y,mouse.r);
  circle(mouse.x,mouse.y,1,'grey');
  var di = {
    x: mouse.x - half.w, // orange
    y: mouse.y - half.h  // green
  }
  di.v = dist(di.x,di.y);
  var a = Math.atan2(di.y,di.x); // angle
  line(mouse.x - di.x,mouse.y,mouse.x,mouse.y,'orange');
  line(mouse.x,mouse.y - di.y,mouse.x,mouse.y,'green');
  var p1 = {
    v: di.v + mouse.r // cyan
  }; 
  p1.x = half.w + (Math.cos(a) * p1.v);
  p1.y = half.h + (Math.sin(a) * p1.v);
  circle(p1.x,p1.y,1.5,'cyan');
  var p2 = {
    v: di.v - mouse.r // red
  };
  p2.x = half.w+Math.cos(a)*p2.v;
  p2.y = half.h+Math.sin(a)*p2.v;
  circle(p2.x,p2.y,1.5,'red');
  var rp1 = {
    v: Math.pow(fixedRadius,2) / p1.v // cyan
  };
  rp1.x = Math.cos(a) * rp1.v,
  rp1.y = Math.sin(a) * rp1.v;
  circle(rp1.x+half.w,rp1.y+half.h,1.5,'cyan');
  var rp2 = {
    v: Math.pow(fixedRadius,2) / p2.v // red
  };
  rp2.x = Math.cos(a) * rp2.v,
  rp2.y = Math.sin(a) * rp2.v;
  circle(rp2.x+half.w,rp2.y+half.h,1.5,'red');
  var newDi = {
    v: dist(rp1.x - rp2.x, rp1.y - rp2.y)
  };   
  newDi.r = newDi.v/2,
  newDi.x = rp1.x + (Math.cos(a) * newDi.r), // yellow
  newDi.y = rp1.y + (Math.sin(a) * newDi.r); // purple
  if (p2.v < 0) {
    newDi.x = rp1.x - (Math.cos(a) * newDi.r),
    newDi.y = rp1.y - (Math.sin(a) * newDi.r);
  }
  reflect.x = half.w+newDi.x;
  reflect.y = half.h+newDi.y
  // reflected lines
  if (di.v<fixedRadius) line(rp1.x+half.w,rp1.y+half.h,p1.x,p1.y,'cyan');
  else line(rp2.x+half.w,rp2.y+half.h,p2.x,p2.y,'red');
  line(p1.x,p1.y,half.w,half.h,'#ccc');
  line(rp2.x+half.w,rp2.y+half.h,half.w,half.h,'#ccc');
  line(reflect.x-newDi.x,reflect.y,reflect.x,reflect.y,'yellow');
  line(reflect.x,reflect.y-newDi.y,reflect.x,reflect.y,'purple');
  // reflected circle
  circle(reflect.x, reflect.y, newDi.r);
  circle(reflect.x,reflect.y,1,'grey');
  circles(); // saved circles
  reflect.r = newDi.r;
};

var dist = function(x,y) {
  return Math.pow(x*x + y*y, 1/2);
};

var scroll = function(evt) {
  if(evt.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
    mouse.r++;
  } else {
    mouse.r--;
  }
  move(evt);
};

var click = function(evt) {
  saved.push(['c',mouse.x,mouse.y,mouse.r]);
  saved.push(['c',reflect.x,reflect.y,reflect.r]);
  saved.push(['l',mouse.x,mouse.y,reflect.x,reflect.y]);
};

var circles = function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < saved.length; i++) {
    var s = saved[i];
    if (s[0]=='c') circle(s[1],s[2],s[3],'grey');
    if (s[0]=='l') line(s[1],s[2],s[3],s[4],'grey');
  }
};

$(setup);
$(window)
  .on('resize', setup)
  .on('mousemove', move)
  .on('mousewheel', scroll)
  .on('click', click);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, inverting the centre of a circle doesn't give you the centre of the other one. Likewise if we invert two oposite points of one circle, it doesn't mean they'll be opposing points on the inverted circle.
Since three points describe a unique circle we can use these to find the equation for the inverse circle. That gives us the centre of the inverse circle. We can then find the distance from the centre to one of the inverted points, that's the radius.

The following c++ code gives the centre. (I don't know javascript). The function v.norm2() gives the squared norm of the vector v.

```
Vector2D getcircle(Vector2D p1, Vector2D p2, Vector2D p3){
    Vector2D result;
    long double div = 2*(p1.x*(p2.y-p3.y)-p1.y*(p2.x-p3.x)+p2.x*p3.y-p3.x*p2.y);
    result.x = (p1.norm2()*(p2.y-p3.y)+p2.norm2()*(p3.y-p1.y)+p3.norm2()*(p1.y-p2.y))/div;
    result.y = (p1.norm2()*(p3.x-p2.x)+p2.norm2()*(p1.x-p3.x)+p3.norm2()*(p2.x-p1.x))/div;
    return result;
}
```

So if you have a circle c of radius r, and you are inverting respect to another circle C and radius R, you could do something like

```
float getRadius(Vector2D C, float R, Vector2D c, float r){
    Vector2D p1 = Vector2D(c.x + r, c.y).invert(C, R);
    Vector2D p2 = Vector2D(c.x - r, c.y).invert(C, R);
    Vector2D p3 = Vector2D(c.x, c.y + r).invert(C, R);
    return (getcircle(p1, p2, p3) - p1).norm();
}
```

Here is an image of a circle with centre (130, -130) and radius 128, and it's inversion respect to another circle (not shown) of centre (0, 0) and radius 40.
The red points on the big circle are polar opposites. They are then inverted and shown on the little circle where you can see they are not polar opposites.

[image: a circle and it's inversion]

Comment: "if we invert two oposite points of one circle, it doesn't mean they'll be opposing points on the inverted circle" why not? It seems to me like it will always be the case. Can you show me an example that proves of your statement please?

Comment: Edited the answer to show a proof. The fact there's almost no yellow in the little circle shows the distortion of the circumference. (Most of it is behind the topmost red dot).

Comment: Sorry but that's not a proof. That low resolution image at it's best shows that there's something wrong with your code. Take a new look at my updated [pen](https://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/Mwjdga) and re-check if it's really possible to distort the circle.

Comment: I hope [this](https://codepen.io/TheInverter/pen/pqwVKX) is proof enough. It is a heavily modified version of your code. In your example, if you put the mouse at the origin, the inverted circle turns into a line. This shouldn't happen. Your code assumes what you want to prove to prove what you want to prove and therefore isn't a valid proof.

Comment: Thanks, you are right about my code not handling this special case right (mouse distance from the center < mouse radius). But I fixed this easily with a simple if statement. Now the code is working 100% and it proves that you only need two opposite points to achieve this. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. What my code does is show where green and red dots show up on the original circle and on the inverted circle. whilst they are always polar opposites on the original circle, they're not always opposites on the inverted circle and so you can't always use 2 points to find the radius of the inverted circle.

Comment: I think what you are not getting is that I only use the opposites that are collinear with the centers. That condition will keep the points in place as you can see in this [edited version of your code](https://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/OrjLBK). As you can see, the red and green dots will always be opposites on both circles